# Como actualizar un dato en Sqlite3 con variables

Tags: python-3.x, crud, sqlite3

Buen día. El asunto es que estoy creando un programa de gestión de usuarios, y tengo problemas para actualizar el usuario mediante variables. Esto es lo que he hecho de momento. Gracias por su ayuda.

```
import sqlite3

database = sqlite3.connect("SUN.db")

lector = database.cursor()

usuario_a_consultar = int(input("Digite el ID del usuario a modificar: "))
        lector.execute("SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE ID = ?", (usuario_a_consultar,))
        print(lector.fetchall())
        print("1.) Nombre")
        a=int(input("¿Que desea modificar del usuario?: "))
        if (a == 1):
            nuevo_nombre = input("Digite el nuevo nombre: ")
            lector.execute("UPDATE USUARIOS SET USUARIO = %s WHERE ID = %s" %(nuevo_nombre,usuario_a_consultar))

database.commit()
database.close()
```

Cuando creo un usuario e intento modificar su nombre ocurre este error:
lector.execute("UPDATE USUARIOS SET USUARIO = %s WHERE ID = %s" %(nuevo_nombre,usuario_a_consultar))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Frank

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: lector.execute("UPDATE USUARIOS SET USUARIO = %s WHERE ID = %s" %(nuevo_nombre,usuario_a_consultar))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Frank

Comment: Cree un usuario llamado Fran y queria cambiar su nombre a Frank pero ocurre este error